# Acess a widget from another class?

Tags: python, wxpython, wxwidgets, instance-variables

I am trying to update a wx.ListCtrl from another class. This is driving me crazy, and I don't understand what exactly I'm doing wrong. The widget is created inside a wx.Frame like:

```
class DataTable(gridlib.GridTableBase):
    def __init__(self, data):

        gridlib.GridTableBase.__init__(self)
        self.data = data
       
        #Store the row and col length to see if table has changed in size
        self._rows = self.GetNumberRows()
        self._cols = self.GetNumberCols()

        print(self._rows, self._cols)

        self.odd=gridlib.GridCellAttr()
        self.odd.SetBackgroundColour((217,217,217))
        self.even=gridlib.GridCellAttr()
        self.even.SetBackgroundColour((255,255,255))

    def GetAttr(self, row, col, kind):
        attr = [self.even, self.odd][row % 2]
        attr.IncRef()
        return attr

    def GetNumberRows(self):
        return len(self.data)

    def GetNumberCols(self):
        return len(self.data.columns) + 1

    def IsEmptyCell(self, row, col):
        return False

    def GetValue(self, row, col):
        if col == 0:
            pass
        #    return None #self.data.index[row]
        else:
            return self.data.iloc[row, col-1]

    def SetValue(self, row, col, value):
        if col == 0:
            pass
        else:
            self.data.iloc[row, col - 1] = value
    
    def GetColLabelValue(self, col):
        try:
            if col == 0:
                return ""
                #return 'Index' if self.data.index.name is None else self.data.index.name
            else:
                return self.data.columns[col - 1] #[col-1]
        except:
            pass

class DataGrid(gridlib.Grid):
def __init__(self, parent, data): # data
        gridlib.Grid.__init__(self, parent, - 1) #,colnames,-1 # data

        self.table = DataTable(data)
        self.SetTable(self.table, True)
        self.Bind(wx.grid.EVT_GRID_CELL_CHANGED, self.onCellChanged)
        
    
    def onCellChanged(self,event):
        #Establish connection
        self.connect_mysql()
        #Update database
        key_id =  str("'") + self.GetCellValue(event.GetRow(),1) +  str("'")    #FOR TESTING. CHANGE TO 0 WHEN IMPORT IS FIXED
        target_col = self.GetColLabelValue(event.GetCol())
        key_col = self.GetColLabelValue(1)                                     #FOR TESTING. CHANGE TO 0 WHEN IMPORT IS FIXED
        nVal = str("'") + self.GetCellValue(event.GetRow(),event.GetCol()) +  str("'")
        sql_update = "UPDATE " + tbl + " SET " +  target_col + " = " + nVal + " WHERE " + key_col  +  " = " + key_id + ""

        try:
            self.cursor.execute(sql_update)
            stat = "UPDATE"
            oVal = event.GetString()
            action = "UPDATE"
            msg =  "Changed " + str("'") + oVal + str("'") + " to " + nVal + " for " + key_id + " in table: " + str("'") + tbl + str("'") 
        #self.updateStatus()
        except:
            stat = "ERROR"
            msg = "ERROR: Failed to update SQL table. " + "'" + tbl + "'"
            self.db_con.rollback()

       #Update dataframe

       #Log the change
       #MainFrame.test_print(stat,msg)      
       #MainFrame.lc_change.Append(["1","2", "3" + "\n"])
       
       #Close connection
        self.close_connection()

class MainFrame(wx.Frame):
    def __init__(self, parent, data): # (self, parent, data):
        wx.Frame.__init__(self, parent, -1, "Varkey Foundation") #, size=(640,480))
        #Create a panel
        self.p = wx.Panel(self)
        self.Maximize(True)
        
        #Create blank dataframe
        data = pd.DataFrame() #pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(0,100,size=(200, 5)),columns=list('EFGHD')
        #data.reset_index(drop=True, inplace=True)
        self.data = DataTable(data)
        
        self.nb = wx.Notebook(self.p)
        self.p.SetBackgroundColour( wx.Colour( 0, 0, 0 ) ) # 38,38,38
        self.nb.SetBackgroundColour(wx.Colour(58, 56, 56) )
        #self.SetBackgroundColour( wx.Colour( 255, 255, 56 ) )

        #create the page windows as children of the notebook
        self.page1 = PageOne(self.nb)
        self.page2 = PageTwo(self.nb)
        self.page3 = PageThree(self.nb)

        # add the pages to the notebook with the label to show on the tab
        self.nb.AddPage(self.page1, "Data")
        self.nb.AddPage(self.page2, "Analyze")
        self.nb.AddPage(self.page3, "Change Log")

        #Create the grid and continue layout
        self.grid = DataGrid(self.page1, data)
        #grid.SetReadOnly(5,5, True)
        
        #CreateFonts
        self.b_font = wx.Font(14,wx.ROMAN,wx.NORMAL,wx.BOLD, True)
        self.lbl_font = wx.Font(14,wx.ROMAN,wx.NORMAL,wx.NORMAL, True)
        self.cb_font = wx.Font(11,wx.SCRIPT,wx.ITALIC,wx.NORMAL, True)
        self.h_font = wx.Font(18,wx.DECORATIVE,wx.ITALIC,wx.BOLD, True)
        #Create Title bmp
        ico = wx.Icon('varkey_bmp.bmp', wx.BITMAP_TYPE_ICO) #'varkey_frame.bmp'
        self.SetIcon(ico)

        #Page 1 sizers and widgets
        self.title = wx.StaticText(self.page1,label="TITLE",style = wx.ALIGN_CENTER | wx.ST_NO_AUTORESIZE)
        self.title.SetForegroundColour((255,255,255))
        self.title.SetFont(self.h_font)
        self.p1_sizer = wx.BoxSizer(wx.VERTICAL)
        self.p1_sizer.Add(self.title,0,wx.EXPAND,5)
        self.p1_sizer.Add(self.grid,3,wx.EXPAND | wx.LEFT | wx.RIGHT | wx.BOTTOM ,25)
        #self.p1_sizer.Add(self.btn_new,-0,wx.ALIGN_CENTER,5)
        self.page1.SetSizer(self.p1_sizer)
        
        #Page 2 sizers and widgets
        self.analyze_grid = gridlib.Grid(self.page2)
        self.analyze_grid.CreateGrid(0, 10)

        self.p2_sizer = wx.BoxSizer(wx.VERTICAL)
        self.p2_sizer.Add(self.analyze_grid,1,wx.EXPAND)
        self.page2.SetSizer(self.p2_sizer)
        
        #Page 3 sizers and widgets
        self.log_grid = gridlib.Grid(self.page3)
        self.log_grid.CreateGrid(0, 9)
        self.log_grid.EnableEditing(False)
       
        self.p3_sizer = wx.BoxSizer(wx.VERTICAL)
        self.p3_sizer.Add(self.log_grid,1,wx.EXPAND)
        self.page3.SetSizer(self.p3_sizer)

        #Create widgets for top sizer
        #Insert Image
        self.staticbitmap = wx.StaticBitmap(self.p)
        self.staticbitmap.SetBitmap(wx.Bitmap('varkey_logo2.jpg'))
        self
        self.lbl_user = wx.StaticText(self.p,label="Username:")
        self.lbl_password = wx.StaticText(self.p,label="Password:")
        self.lbl_interaction = wx.StaticText(self.p,label="Interaction:")
        self.lbl_table = wx.StaticText(self.p,label="Table:")
        #SetForground colors
        self.lbl_user.SetForegroundColour((255,255,255))
        self.lbl_password.SetForegroundColour((255,255,255))
        self.lbl_interaction.SetForegroundColour((255,255,255))
        self.lbl_table.SetForegroundColour((255,255,255))

        #Set Fonts
        self.lbl_user.SetFont(self.lbl_font)
        self.lbl_password.SetFont(self.lbl_font)
        self.lbl_interaction.SetFont(self.lbl_font)
        self.lbl_table.SetFont(self.lbl_font)

        self.tc_user =wx.TextCtrl(self.p,value='cmccall95',size = (130,25))
        self.tc_password =wx.TextCtrl(self.p,value='Achilles95', style=wx.TE_PASSWORD | wx.TE_PROCESS_ENTER,size = (130,25))
        self.tc_password.Bind(wx.EVT_TEXT_ENTER,self.onLogin)
        self.tc_user.SetFont(self.cb_font)
        self.tc_password.SetFont(self.cb_font)

        self.btn_login = wx.Button(self.p,label="Login", size=(105,30))
        self.btn_login.SetBackgroundColour(wx.Colour(198, 89, 17))
        self.btn_login.SetFont(self.b_font)
        self.btn_login.Bind(wx.EVT_BUTTON, self.onLogin) #connect_mysql

        self.btn_logout = wx.Button(self.p,label="Logout",size=(105,30))
        self.btn_logout.SetBackgroundColour(wx.Colour(192,0,0))
        self.btn_logout.SetFont(self.b_font)
        #self.btn_logout.Bind(wx.EVT_BUTTON, self.onLogout)


        self.combo_interaction = wx.ComboBox(self.p, size = (160,25),style = wx.CB_READONLY | wx.CB_SORT | wx.CB_SORT)
        self.combo_interaction.Bind(wx.EVT_COMBOBOX, self.onComboInteraction)
        self.combo_table = wx.ComboBox(self.p, size = (160,25),style = wx.CB_READONLY | wx.CB_SORT | wx.CB_SORT)
        self.combo_table.Bind(wx.EVT_COMBOBOX, self.onHideCommands)
        self.combo_interaction.SetFont(self.cb_font)
        self.combo_table.SetFont(self.cb_font)

        #self.combo_table.Bind(wx.EVT_COMBOBOX         ,self.OnComboTable)
        self.btn_load  = wx.Button(self.p,label="Load Table", size=(105,30))
        self.btn_load.SetBackgroundColour(wx.Colour(31, 216, 6))
        self.btn_load.SetFont(self.b_font)
        #self.btn_load.Bind(wx.EVT_BUTTON, self.onLoadData)
        self.btn_load.Bind(wx.EVT_BUTTON, self.test_reload)

        self.lc_change = wx.ListCtrl(self.p,-1,style = wx.TE_MULTILINE | wx.LC_REPORT | wx.LC_VRULES)
        self.lc_change.InsertColumn(0,"User ID")
        self.lc_change.InsertColumn(1,"Status")
        self.lc_change.InsertColumn(2,"Description")
        self.lc_change.InsertColumn(3,"Date/Time")
        #Set column widths
        self.lc_change.SetColumnWidth(0, 75)
        self.lc_change.SetColumnWidth(1, 75)
        self.lc_change.SetColumnWidth(2, 450)
        self.lc_change.SetColumnWidth(3, 125)

       
        #Add Row Button
        #self.btn_new = wx.Button(self.page1,label="+", size = (35,25))
        #self.btn_new.SetForegroundColour(wx.Colour(112,173,71))
        #self.btn_new.SetFont(self.h_font)
        #self.btn_new.Bind(wx.EVT_BUTTON, self.onInsertRecordBelow)

        #Create Filler text
        self.lbl_filler = wx.StaticText(self.p,label="",size = (125,20))
        #Create FlexGridSizers(For top half)
        self.left_fgs = wx.FlexGridSizer(3,4,25,15)
        self.left_fgs.AddMany([(self.lbl_user,1,wx.ALIGN_LEFT | wx.LEFT,15),(self.tc_user,1,wx.EXPAND),(self.lbl_interaction,1,wx.ALIGN_RIGHT|wx.RIGHT, 10),(self.combo_interaction,1,wx.EXPAND),
                               (self.lbl_password,1,wx.ALIGN_LEFT| wx.LEFT,15),(self.tc_password,1,wx.EXPAND),(self.lbl_table,1,wx.ALIGN_RIGHT|wx.RIGHT, 10),(self.combo_table),
                               (self.btn_login,2,wx.EXPAND),(self.btn_logout,1,wx.EXPAND),(self.lbl_filler,1,wx.EXPAND),(self.btn_load,1)])

        #Create Top Sizer 
        self.top_sizer = wx.BoxSizer(wx.HORIZONTAL)
        self.top_sizer.Add(self.left_fgs,proportion = 1, flag = wx.ALL|wx.EXPAND,border = 30)
        self.top_sizer.Add(self.staticbitmap,2,wx.TOP | wx.RIGHT, border = 40) #30
        self.top_sizer.Add(self.lc_change,2,wx.RIGHT|wx.EXPAND ,30)

        #create Bottom Sizer
        self.bottom_sizer = wx.BoxSizer(wx.VERTICAL)
        self.bottom_sizer.Add(self.nb,proportion = 5, flag = wx.LEFT |wx.RIGHT | wx.EXPAND,border = 30)
        
        self.mainsizer = wx.BoxSizer(wx.VERTICAL)
        self.mainsizer.Add(self.top_sizer,proportion = 0, flag = wx.ALL|wx.EXPAND,border = 5)
        self.mainsizer.Add(self.bottom_sizer,proportion = 1,flag = wx.ALL|wx.EXPAND,border = 5)
        #self.mainsizer.Add(self.status_sizer,proportion =0,flag = wx.BOTTOM|wx.ALIGN_CENTER_HORIZONTAL, border = 15)
        self.p.SetSizerAndFit(self.mainsizer)

        self.hideWidgets()
        self.onHideCommands(self)

#### Some functions...

if __name__ == '__main__':
    import sys
    app = wx.App()
    frame = MainFrame(None, sys.stdout) # (None, sys.stdout)
    frame.Show(True)
    app.MainLoop()
```

I have another grid class where have some bound events.

```
class DataGrid(gridlib.Grid):
    def __init__(self, parent, data):
        gridlib.Grid.__init__(self, parent, - 1) #,colnames,-1 

        self.table = DataTable(data)
        self.SetTable(self.table, True)
        self.Bind(gridlib.EVT_GRID_CELL_RIGHT_CLICK, self.OnCellRightClick)
        self.Bind(wx.grid.EVT_GRID_CELL_CHANGED, self.onCellChanged)

def onCellChanged(self,event):
       
       try:   
            
            stat = "UPDATE"
            msg =  "Changed " + str("'") + self.oVal + str("'") + " to " + self.nVal + " for " + self.key_id + " in table: " + str("'") + tbl + str("'") 
         
       except:
            stat = "ERROR"
            msg = "ERROR: Failed to update SQL table. " + "'" + tbl + "'"
            #self.updateStatus()
            

       #MainFrame.test_print(stat,msg)      
       #self.MainFrame.lc_change.Append(["1","2", "3" + "\n"])
```

I have tried passing it directly to a function.

```
MainFrame.test_print(stat,msg)
```

Which works to pass the variables. The problem is when using "self", I get an error.

Then I've tried accessing the list control directly:

```
self.MainFrame.lc_change.Append(["1","2", "3" + "\n"])
```

And:

```
MainFrame.lc_change.Append(["1","2", "3" + "\n"])
```

These 2 give me "type object 'xxx' has no attribute 'xxx'

Can anyone tell me what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Please update your question with the code where MainFrame and DataGrid are instantiated.

Comment: Edited, I left out a lot of functions to shorten the length. I also added in the GridTableClass

Comment: Usually, in situations like these, ir's easiest to reference the `parent`. So in the `__init__` you simply use `self.parent = parent` then later you would access the widget with `self.parent.lc` in this case. Of course, it does rely on declaring it as `self.lc` in the `parent` class.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you need to do is to be able to allow the `DataGrid` to have a reference to the `wx.ListCtrl` that `MainFrame` creates.

```py
class MainFrame(wx.Frame):
    def __init__(self, parent, data): # (self, parent, data):
        wx.Frame.__init__(self, parent, -1, "Varkey Foundation") #, size=(640,480))
        #Create a panel
        self.p = wx.Panel(self)
        #Create the ListCtrl here:
        self.lc_change = wx.ListCtrl(self.p,-1,style = wx.TE_MULTILINE | wx.LC_REPORT | wx.LC_VRULES)

        ...
        # Later when you create the DataGrid:
        #Create the grid and continue layout
        self.grid = DataGrid(self.page1, data, self.lc_change)  # pass in the ListCtrl
        ...

class DataGrid(gridlib.Grid):
    def __init__(self, parent, data, lc):
        gridlib.Grid.__init__(self, parent, - 1) #,colnames,-1 

        self.lc = lc
        ...

    def onCellChanged(self,event):
        ...
       self.lc.Append(["1","2", "3" + "\n"])  # Now update the ListCtrl
```